# snd-hda-intel only showing up one audio output device (HMDI) also no input device

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, devices

So I added snd-hda-intel option to alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

but I'm only getting one output device which is the HDMI. The actual motherboard audio card is not working, including the internal laptop mic. I've tried also using auto setting but still not working.

My device is definitely listed as snd-hda-intel device in lspci but it's not showing up! Please help!

[lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/948Og.png)

[Audio output devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLYrP.png)

EDIT:
ubuntu 23.04 and kernel version updated to 6.4.6

Comment: ubuntu 23.04 and kernel version updated to 6.4.6